# Threats / drawbacks behind ISNULL(), NULLIF(), and COALESCE()

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, null, concatenation

I am working on a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 with Transact-SQL.

I am trying to concatenate string values coming from different columns of the same table dealing with NULL values.

Say for example the table is `Person` and the columns are `FirstName`, `SurnamePrefix`, `LegalSurname`

It happened that concatenating a string value with a NULL value (coming from two different columns) returns in output a NULL value.
I tried different scenarios to prevent NULL values in output:

- Starting from:

  - `Person.FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(Person.SurnamePrefix)) + ' ', '') + Person.LegalSurname`
- I changed my statement to:

  - `COALESCE(Person.FirstName + ' ', '') + COALESCE(Person.SurnamePrefix, '') + COALESCE(' ' + Person.LegalSurname, '')`

Then I came across functions like `ISNULL()`, `NULLIF()` etc.

Which is the best and efficient approach to show empty strings values in output rather than NULL values?
Is the solution affected by the version of the SQL Server? (i.e. 2005, 2008, etc.)

Comment: 2012 has [`CONCAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) where Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISNULL` is good for default values, as you are doing.  `COALESCE` has the advantage of accepting more than two arguments.  `NULLIF` is quite different as it returns a `NULL` if the arguments are equal.

You can benchmark them for performance.  I suspect that the difference is negligible and that it is far more important to opt for clarity in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but although it is deprecated in future versions of SQL Server, SQL 2005 allows you to set [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) off at connection level. (It's also possible to set it at database level using an `ALTER DATABASE` command, but this is likely to affect the behaviour of existing queries). 
You could set this before running your queries:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

SELECT 'a' + NULL
```

yields the result

```
a
```

From the perspective of maintainability it might be better to avoid doing this - it will confuse the unwary - but it is another alternative to what you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Bertrand [compared](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/) `COALESCE` with `ISNULL` and found no significant performance difference between the two.